# How to reassign id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am generating elements dynamically through jquery and creating dynamic id's for each element.
Now i have also given the provision of removing a specific element through a remove button.
In that case my id for that given element also gets removed.
Now i have to reassign all id's so that all the id's are in sequence.

Eg. 
suppose i generate 4 divs dynamically thru jquery

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
```

Now i remove the 2nd one

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
```

my id's are now box 1, box 3, box 4

but i want them to be box1, box2, and box 3

Comment: Um, why? Can't you have them in a container called `box` and then just `getElementById('box').children[your_number_here]`?

Comment: I agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol, incremental `id` or `class` attributes lead to a maintenance nightmare - especially when they must be in order.

Comment: actually i don't want to get any element thru id. that can be easily done. But because these ids are used inside a table in some db, so if there will be missing ids then all those places in the tables would be empty

Comment: @pdjinn if you don't need to _"get any element"_ then you don't need to give the element an ID.  Just use the elements' indexes to determine their positions as you iterate over them.

Comment: im sorry... but the ids are being used in a table in some database by backend people and they want it sequential because of some table problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this every time you remove a box

```
var $boxes = $('[id^="box"]');
for (var i = 0; i < $boxes.length; i++) {
    $boxes.eq(i).prop('id', 'box' + (i + 1));
}
```

or wrap your boxes with a div and do this

```
$('[id^="box"]').attr('id', function () {
    return "box" + ($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAS9e/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ah there, added .eq()

Comment: Still a horrible solution :p

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, have a common class to all divs

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

every time you remove a div, and in beginning run this function;

```
var reassignIds = function(){
    $('.box').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('id', 'box'+(index+1));
    });
}
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/bjBSs/1/

Comment: `$(this).attr('id', 'string')` is a jQuery anti-pattern

Comment: well, question asked, and what is being done here look anti-pattern to me, I was just answering the question, since I didn't had good enough information to suggest better option.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use sequential IDs, the most concise implementation is this (assuming each box has a common class of `box`):

```
$('.box').each(function(i) {
    this.id = 'box' + (i + 1);
});
```

an alternate implementation would be:

```
$('.box').attr('id', function(i) {
    return 'box' + (i + 1);
});
```

but this isn't as efficient as it ends up creating additional jQuery objects within the loop that `.attr` will run.

However, it would be best not to use sequential IDs at all - you can typically use `.index()` to find the position of a child within its parent whenever you need to.

Comment: actually i need sequential ids for backend purposes.

Answer (score 0):

capture the id of the currently removed item

for example if you are are removing an item on some button click with id say  `#btn` then :

```
$('#btn').click(function(e)

{
 var elemid=($('#box2').attr('id')).split(""); //elemid will be ["b","o","x","2"]

 var id=new Array(); //var id type is array because in case removed item's id contains more than one digit number like box22, box31, box49..

 for(var i=0; i<elemid.length;i++)

 {
   if(!isNaN(parseInt(elemid[i])))
   {
     id.push(elemid[i]); //extract all numbers and push them into id array
   }
 }

  id=parseInt(id.join("")); //join id array contents and change them from string to number

 var parent=$('#box2').parent();

 var pos=$(#box2).index();  //position from where to start changing id(s)

 $('#box2').remove();

 var k=0;

 parent.children('div').each(function(){

    if(k>=pos){
        $(this).attr('id','box'+id)

         id++;
    }
    k++;
  })
})
```